# How to set Coreplot axisLabels width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm working on the axisLabels and need to make the labels side by side with no space in between. However it seems the labels are autosized to the text. Is there a way to set the width of the labels?

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet         = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.weightHistoryChart.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x                  = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1.0, @3.0, @5.0, nil];
NSMutableSet *customLabels   = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:3];

for ( NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations ) {

    CPTTextLayer *layer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"label"];
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:layer];
    newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation;
    newLabel.offset       = 0;
    [newLabel.contentLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
}

x.axisLabels = customLabels;
```

**With space:**

[image]

**Remove space:**

[image: need to remove the space:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the left and right padding on the `CPTTextLayer` to leave extra space on the sides around the text. However, if all you want is a solid rectangle behind the labels, it might look better to add a layer annotation behind the labels.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to use orthogonal points to set the size of the layer, instead of using actual screen points? Cheers.

Comment: The reason I was asking is that I need to resize the X Axis labels when screen orientation changes. I'm hoping that once the textLayer's size/padding is set by coordinate points, there's no need to do the resizing for orientations.

Comment: That's why I suggested the annotation behind the labels. Use a `CPTBorderedLayer` for the annotation content layer and it won't have to resize or move unless the graph does.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I tried to add annotation but it's not showing..
`CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *anno = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:self.chart.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:@[@(30), @(60)]];
        anno.displacement = CGPointMake(20, 50);
        
        CPTBorderedLayer *bLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] init];
        bLayer.fill = [[CPTFill alloc] initWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[FSColorFactory weightChartDateLabelBGColor].CGColor]];
        anno.contentLayer = bLayer;
        
        [self.chart.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:anno];`

Comment: Use `initWithFrame:` when creating the bordered layer and give it the desired size. `init` create a layer with zero width and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116624/discussion-between-bonan-and-eric-skroch).